# How to make this htaccess not redirect or change the url?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).addon.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://main.net/subfolder/%1.addon.com/$1 [L]
```

It's the final step for one of my projects.

Your help will be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the proxy flag in your rule. It basically sends your request to `mod_proxy` for further processing - a 'proxy request'.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://main.net/subfolder/%1.addon.com/$1 [P]
```

Nore that use of the proxy flag automatically implies the `last` or `L` flag, where no further rules will be taken into account as another server is now handling the request.